# saving an image with custom names in openCV 2.4.9

Tags: android, opencv, mat

I want to modify an application from https://eaglesky.github.io/2015/12/26/HandGestureRecognition/. 
It is an application that recognizes sign language. When im adding a new gesture, it goes to the mydataset folder with a filename of 1,2,3,4,5.jpg and so on. What i want is to make custom name before saving the gestures.

Edited: the full code is on the link above located at app>java>com.example.newdemo>MainActivity

here is the code

```
boolean savePicture()
    {
        Mat img;



        if (((mode == BACKGROUND_MODE) || (mode == SAMPLE_MODE)
                || (mode == TRAIN_REC_MODE)) || (mode == ADD_MODE) || 
                (mode == TEST_MODE)) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaMat, bgrMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);
            img = bgrMat;
        } else if (mode == DETECTION_MODE) {
            img = binMat;
        } else 
            img = null;

        if (img != null) {
             if (!isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        //       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "External storage is not writable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  return false;
             }

             File path;
             String filename;
             if (mode != ADD_MODE) {
                 path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                 filename = "image_" + imgNum + ".jpg";
             } else {
                 path = storeFolder;
                 filename = curLabel + ".jpg";
             }


             imgNum++;
             File file = new File(path, filename);



              Boolean bool = false;
              filename = file.toString();


              bool = Highgui.imwrite(filename, img);

              if (bool == true) {
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved as " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Log.d(TAG, "Succeed writing image to" + filename);
              } else
                Log.d(TAG, "Fail writing image to external storage");

              return bool;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you locate the piece of code that handles saving?

Comment: @hkchengrex i updated the my question sir.

Comment: I would say that the `fileName` variable stores the name of the file to be saved. If you want custom name, try changing that variable to whatever you wanted.